# Mask raster function in R not working to extract values in one raster based on conditions in another

Tags: raster, r, extract-by-mask

**require:** raster package

I am having trouble masking values of one raster using values in another.  This is similar to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716315/how-to-subset-classify-raster-based-on-another-raster-grid-cells-values

but it doesn't have the moving window (focal function) as a component of the question.  I have two rasters with the same dimension, extent, projection.

**Raster "MAT2resampled" is a raster with a wide range of temperature indices**
[image]
**Raster "wintPCP" is a second raster with pixel values of 1, O, and NA**
[image]

The only pixels I want from MAT2resampled are those with the value 1 in wintPCP.

I used this code:
`PthreshWint2 <- mask(MAT2resampled, wintPCP)`

When I plot PthreshWint2, it doesn't appear as though the MAT2resampled raster has been masked at all.  I think I'm missing something simple.

[image]

I have posted the two rasters here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=118kCu6QpoXSYmA17PpODRhHDJefHPkx1

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N062TiHTHBqRYrclRW8O87WY-MX8taQg

Comment: Change the values of 0 in wintPCP to NA first then mask

Comment: Please try and make examples with smaller data sets - these are way too large for many people to bother downloading. If you can create sample data in code then that's even better.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mask with 0, 1, and NA values and you want to keep only the 1s. Hence you need to convert 0 and NA to the same value.

Here's a bit of a trick. Diving `m` by itself results in NA where `m` is 0 or NA (since 0/0 returns NaN, which acts like NA in `mask`) and 1 where its 1:

```
rmask = mask(r,m/m)
```

not sure if that's any quicker than the other solutions.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a slick little trick.  Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

First change the values of 0 in wintPCP to NA:

`wintPCP[wintPCP == 0] <- NA`

then mask:

`masked_ras <- mask(MAT2resampled, wintPCP)`

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  Wasn't obvious that I needed to include that step.